# FragmentTransaction replace keep old fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm using fragment.replace to lunch a list of user in a chat application using parse and sinch,at the begin i'm using views but now I'm changing to fragments, but the place just append instead of replace the fragment. I'm using android.support.v4.app.Fragment,FragmentManager and FragmentTransaction. What am I doing wrong .
Here's my class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.parse.LogInCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseUser;
import com.parse.SignUpCallback;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.example.paul.mapasxavo.ListUsersActivity;
import com.example.paul.mapasxavo.R;
public class ChatActivity extends Fragment  {

    private Button signUpButton;
    private Button loginButton;
    private EditText usernameField;
    private EditText passwordField;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Intent intent;
    private Intent serviceIntent;
    Context thiscontext;
    private final String TAG="ChatActivity";

    public ChatActivity(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (currentUser != null) {

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
        }

    @Override
    public  View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_chat, container, false);
        loginButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        signUpButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.signupButton);
        usernameField = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loginUsername);
        passwordField = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        loginButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        signUpButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.signupButton);
        usernameField = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loginUsername);
        passwordField = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                username = usernameField.getText().toString();
                password = passwordField.getText().toString();

                ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseUser user, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            ListUsersActivity listUsersActivity = new ListUsersActivity();
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager= getFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.listados,listUsersActivity);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            Log.v(TAG,"boton login");
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                    getString(R.string.login_error),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                username = usernameField.getText().toString();
                password = passwordField.getText().toString();

                ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
                user.setUsername(username);
                user.setPassword(password);

                user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                    public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {

                            ListUsersActivity listUsersActivity = new ListUsersActivity();
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager= getFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.listados,listUsersActivity);
                            fragmentTransaction.commit();
                            Log.v(TAG,"boton registrar");

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                    getString(R.string.sigin_error)
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });



        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My fragment is this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.paul.mapasxavo.ChatActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/listados"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="@string/txt_usuario"
            android:id="@+id/loginUsernameText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/loginUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp">
            <requestFocus/>
        </EditText>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="@string/txt_password"
            android:id="@+id/loginPasswordText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp">
        </EditText>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <Button
                style="@style/botones"
                android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                android:layout_width="168dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Login"
                />
            <Button
                style="@style/botones"
                android:id="@+id/signupButton"
                android:layout_width="163dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Registrar"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My replace fragment is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.paul.mapasxavo.ListUsersActivity">

    <Button
        style="@style/botones"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/logout"
        android:id="@+id/logoutButton"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:padding="15dp"
         />
    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/usersListView">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please give a hint. 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Searchin inside the forum, found some anwers, based on this [link][[Android Replace Fragment within a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378716/android-replace-fragment-within-a-fragment]). I could make it work making some changes in fragment transaction and xml.

**Chat Activity:**

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
username = usernameField.getText().toString();
password = passwordField.getText().toString();
ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
public void done(ParseUser user, com.parse.ParseException e) {
if (user != null) {
FragmentManager fragmentManager = myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
//start transaction
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ListUsersActivity listUsersActivity = new ListUsersActivity();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("xyz");                            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.listados,listUsersActivity);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
serviceIntent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MessageService.class);
getActivity().startService(serviceIntent);
} else {
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
getString(R.string.login_error),
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
);
}
});
```

**activity_chat.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/listados"
    tools:context="com.example.paul.mapasxavo.ChatActivity">
```

Now it show as a a new layer over the last one.

Comment: I use myContext as FragmentActivity but still doesn't work, the fragment is overlaping the other fragment, is correct this assignation or  I making wrong ?